# Use Grouping in G-sheets after locking the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to lock a sheet but the person who looks at it should be able to use the grouping on the left site.

I know the script/VBA  for MS Excel but cant translate it in Google Script. This is the VBA Code for MS excel:

```
Sub Workbook_Open() 
    ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True, Password:="Passwort"
    ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True 'für Gliederung
    ActiveSheet.EnableAutoFilter = True 'für Autofilter 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, to avoid getting the question closed because poor quality I would suggest editing the question and adding some actual code to help you with. For a further reference check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and for this specific question [mcve]

Comment: This is the VBA Code for MS excel                
Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True, Password:="Passwort"
ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True 'für Gliederung
ActiveSheet.EnableAutoFilter = True 'für Autofilter
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting cannot be accomplished in Google Sheets. Unlike Excel which allows you to protect against specified actions, Google Sheets only protects against editing a cell.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en